# VBA Outlook Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to run this to macro to move an email attachment from a folder in my inbox (called toolkit downloads) into a folder on my desktop and rename the attachment.

I get

> Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

```
Sub OSP()

Dim oOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim oNs As Outlook.NameSpace 'Main Outlook Today
Dim oFldrSb As Outlook.MAPIFolder 'Sub Folder in Outlook Today
Dim oFldrSbSb As Outlook.MAPIFolder 'Sub in Sub Folder
Dim oFldrSbSbsb As Outlook.MAPIFolder 'Sub in Sub in Sub Folder

Dim oMessage As Object
Dim sPathName As String
Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim Ictr As Integer
Dim iAttachCnt As Integer

sPathName = "H:\Desktop\Toolkit Downloads\" 'My Folder Path where to save attachments

Set oOutlook = New Outlook.Application
Set oNs = oOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oFldrSb = oNs.Folders("Joe.Bloggs@test.co.uk")
Set oFldrSbSb = oFldrSb.Folders("Inbox")
Set oFldrSbSbsb = oFldrSbSb.Folders("Toolkit Downloads")

For Each oMessage In oFldrSbSbsb.Items

    With oMessage.Attachments 
        iAttachCnt = .Count

        If iAttachCnt > 0 Then
            For Ictr = 1 To iAttachCnt
                .Item(Ictr).SaveAsFile sPathName _
                & .Item(Ictr).Parent
            Next Ictr
        End If
    End With

DoEvents

Next oMessage

SaveAttachments = True

MsgBox "All Indepol Download files have been moved !!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "It worked... Yahoo"

End Sub
```

Comment: Which statement gives error 438?

Comment: Is there anything in Folders("Toolkit Downloads") that is not a MailItem?  Only MailItems have attachments.

Comment: Why are you using .`Item(Ictr).Parent` as part of the output file name?  I have never tried but would guess the parent of an attachment is the MailItem   A MailItem is not a string so cannot be used in this way. You cannot guarantee that any name like this is unique without testing.

Comment: Hiya Tony many thanks for responding.  I have to admit I am a novice at VBA and was given the script to use so am not sure why Item(Ictr).Parent was used .  The error 438 doesn't seem to highlight a statement. I can confirm that ionly emails with attachments are in the Toolkit Downloads folder.

Comment: Hiya Tony just found the error, it seems to be in  .Item(Ictr).SaveAsFile sPathName _
                & .Item(Ictr).Parent

Comment: Have researched further, I do not believe an attachment has property `Parent`. Try property `FileName`. However, if you do, you are relying on each value of `FileName` being unique since you cannot create two files with the same name. A easy trick is to include `Format(Now(),"yymmddhhnnss")` in the save filename.

Comment: To expand on the last comment.  For Outlook 2016, an attachment definitely does not have property Parent.  I think for Outlook 2003, an attachment did have property Parent.  I have not tried the intermediate versions of Outlook.

Comment: Thanks Tony by replacing parent with File name there is now no error. As a VBA novice would you be able to let me know where I should add Format(Now(),"yymmddhhnnss") into the script? Thanks

Comment: Your path is "H:\Desktop\Toolkit Downloads\".  FileName will be "MyPicture.gif" or whatever. `sPathName & .Item(Ictr).FileName` concatenates those to give: "H:\Desktop\Toolkit Downloads\MyPicture.gif".  Note: '&' means 'concatenate' and '_' means 'statement continues on next line'. If you know "MyPicture.gif" is unique, you need do nothing. If the attachments are downloads, this might be true.

Comment: If you are not sure, I would go for `sPathName & Format(...) & " " & .Item(Ictr).FileName` which would give: "H:\Desktop\Toolkit Downloads\170705 095312 MyPicture.gif" if `Now()` is 9:53:12 am on 5 July 2017.

Comment: I note that R3uK suggests `.Subject & .FileName`. I would have suggested `.Subject & ." " & FileName` but only if I knew that subject and filename together were unique and providing subject did not contain characters forbidden in filenames.

Comment: Thanks Tony for all your help I will give it a go

Comment: In my previous comment `.Subject & ." " & FileName` should be `.Subject & " " & .FileName`.  That is, the period before FileName got displaced.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no need to create a new Outlook Application instance if you run the VBA macro in Outlook:

```
Set oOutlook = New Outlook.Application
```

Instead, use the `Application` property available in the defualt module.

The [SaveAsFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/attachment-saveasfile-method-outlook?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method of the `Attachment` class accepts a string which stands for the location at which to save the attachment. Make sure a string is passed there.

In general, I'd suggest debugging the code line by line and find which property or method exactly generates an error. You may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article helpful.

Comment: Many thank Eugene i will have a look at the article. The debug highlights  .Item(Ictr).SaveAsFile sPathName _
                & .Item(Ictr).Parent

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the MailItem object as a string in the method `SaveAsFile`, ergo the error.

I'm guessing that you want to include the mail's subject into the new file name :

```
.Item(Ictr).SaveAsFile sPathName _
    & .Item(Ictr).Parent.Subject
```

And if you have multiples attachments, I'd add the initial file name in there :

```
.Item(Ictr).SaveAsFile sPathName _
    & .Item(Ictr).Parent.Subject
    & .Item(Ictr).FileName
```

---

Full code :

```
Sub OSP()

Dim oOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim oNs As Outlook.NameSpace 'Main Outlook Today
Dim oFldrSb As Outlook.MAPIFolder 'Sub Folder in Outlook Today
Dim oFldrSbSb As Outlook.MAPIFolder 'Sub in Sub Folder
Dim oFldrSbSbsb As Outlook.MAPIFolder 'Sub in Sub in Sub Folder

Dim oMessage As Object
Dim sPathName As String
Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim Ictr As Integer
Dim iAttachCnt As Integer

sPathName = "H:\Desktop\Toolkit Downloads\" 'My Folder Path where to save attachments

Set oOutlook = Application
Set oNs = oOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oFldrSb = oNs.Folders("Joe.Bloggs@test.co.uk")
Set oFldrSbSb = oFldrSb.Folders("Inbox")
Set oFldrSbSbsb = oFldrSbSb.Folders("Toolkit Downloads")

For Each oMessage In oFldrSbSbsb.items

    With oMessage.Attachments
        iAttachCnt = .Count

        If iAttachCnt > 0 Then
            For Ictr = 1 To iAttachCnt
                .Item(Ictr).SaveAsFile sPathName _
                & .Item(Ictr).Parent.Subject
                & .Item(Ictr).FileName
            Next Ictr
        End If
    End With

DoEvents

Next oMessage

SaveAttachments = True

MsgBox "All Indepol Download files have been moved !!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "It worked... Yahoo"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks R3uK for your help I will have a go at running it